# else statement not working in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#loginsubmit').click(function() { 
        var email = $('#email').val();  
        var password = $('#password').val(); 

        if (email != "" && password != "") { 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "User_Actions/PHP_Actions/Login.php",
                data: "email=" + email + "&password=" + password,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loginsubmit').val("...");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#loginsubmit').val('Login');
                    if (data){
                        $('.error-login').html(data);
                        $('.news-login').html("");
                    } else {
                        alert("data");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**IF statement is working corectly but else is not working and no console error!
please solve it its important for me to do!
it was working before but after i worked on it and then it stopped working**

help help help help help help help  help help help help help help help help help help help help help help help help help helphelp helphelphelphelp

Comment: I think you need to define an error function for your AJAX call rather than trying to use an if in the success function.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is the `else` supposed to do? That `data` parameter will probably *never* be "falsy", because it'll always be an object reference.

Comment: Also you should present the ajax parameters as a JavaScript object so that jQuery can properly escape the names and values (or do that yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an error handling in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#loginsubmit').click(function() { 
        var email = $('#email').val();  
        var password = $('#password').val(); 

        if (email != "" && password != "") { 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "User_Actions/PHP_Actions/Login.php",
                data: "email=" + email + "&password=" + password,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loginsubmit').val("...");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#loginsubmit').val('Login');
                    $('.error-login').html(data);
                    $('.news-login').html("");
                },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    console.log( errorThrown );
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe if the POST request always succeeds and no data are returned, you might have a server-side issue with your PHP.
Did you try using POSTMAN to forge the request?

Comment: the data is comming when credentials are given wrong but in if condition when there is no data then nothing happens and i have tried to put if(data == "true") when the login succedes in php file and it echo true then also its showing the error given in else statement and if condition stopped working